# why checkbox are not selected if i click on another tab?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager

when i stay on tab so on a page viewer and i select a checkbox, when i click on another tab the checkbox that i selected before is not selected....why?

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks everybody!!!!!

```
public abstract class BirraAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Birra> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    private List<Birra>birraList;
    private Context context2;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;

    public  BirraAdapter(List<Birra> birraList, Context context2) {
        super(context2, R.layout.single_listview_item_birra, birraList);
        this.birraList = birraList;
        this.context2 = context2;
    }
    public  class BirraHolder  {
        public TextView birraName;
        public TextView birraprezzo;
        public TextView valuta_birra;
        public CheckBox chkBox_birra;
        public EditText edit_birra;
        public String quantità;
    }
      @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
        BirraHolder birraHolder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context2).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item_birra, parent, false);
            birraHolder = new BirraHolder();
            birraHolder.birraName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name_birra);
            birraHolder.birraprezzo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.prezzo_birra);
            birraHolder.valuta_birra = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta_birra);
            birraHolder.chkBox_birra = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box_birra);
            birraHolder.edit_birra = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText_birra);
            birraHolder.edit_birra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            birraHolder.edit_birra.setEnabled(false);
            row.setTag(birraHolder);
        } else {
            birraHolder = (BirraHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Birra b = birraList.get(position);

        birraHolder.chkBox_birra.setOnCheckedChangeListener(BirraAdapter.this);
        final BirraHolder finalHolder = birraHolder;
        birraHolder.chkBox_birra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox_birra.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit_birra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit_birra.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.edit_birra.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            b.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit_birra.getText().toString().trim());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit_birra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit_birra.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit_birra.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });
        birraHolder.birraName.setText(b.getName());
        birraHolder.birraprezzo.setText("" + b.getDistance());
        birraHolder.valuta_birra.setText("" + b.getValuta());
        birraHolder.chkBox_birra.setChecked(b.isSelected());
        birraHolder.chkBox_birra.setTag(b);
        birraHolder.edit_birra.setEnabled(false);
        return row;
    }
    ArrayList<Birra> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Birra> box = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        for (Birra b : birraList) {
            if (b.selected)
                box.add(b);
        }
        return box;
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return  rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7,"€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5,"€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5,"€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };
        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }



    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//*
        }*/

    }


    public void showResult(View v) {
        String  result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;
        String c="";

        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (b.selected){

                result += "\n" + b.name+" "+b.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount+=b.distance * quantitaInt;
                c=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

MAIN

```
public class MainBirra extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainbirra);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().

                replace(R.id.fragmentContainer2, new ThreeFragment()).commit();



    }



}

class Birra {

    String name;
    int distance;
    String quantità;
    String valuta;
    boolean selected = false;



    public Birra(String name, int distance, String valuta) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.valuta = valuta;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getQuantità() {
        return quantità;
    }

    public void setQuantità(String quantità) {
        this.quantità = quantità;
    }
    public String getValuta() {
        return valuta;
    }

    public void setValuta(String valuta) {
        this.valuta = valuta;
    }

}
```

Comment: for the love of god please format your code

Comment: Its getting recycled

Comment: you are using onclicklistener and also onCheckListener.May be your issue is here.Please check this

Comment: @Rama i use onCheckedChange earn i click on checkbox

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make a Boolean array for checkbox and initially set it with false value in adapter.then If user checks the array make array's position true. and On uncheck of checkbox make it false.and then Always set the checkbox value from that Boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the CheckBoxes values to `SharedPrefs` to make them persistent through the app.
values gets lost when you leave activity.

I recommend you to use [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo). Its very light and pretty straight forward to save anything in `SharedPrefs`

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your ***menifests file*** for *related activity* (of both fragment's).

```
 <activity
        android:name=".your_activity_name"
        android:label="@string/per_care"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

Comment: what mean android:launchMode="singleTop"? save values when i change tab?

Comment: in android manifest where i must put " android:launchMode="singleTop"?

Comment: i use fragment and i don t have fragment in android manifest.xml

Comment: from which activity your fragment relates to?

Comment: i writed "    <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainBirra"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />" but doesn't work